# How can I make some objects to move between waypoints?

Tags: unity, c#

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;
    
    public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<GameObject> objectsToTeleport = new List<GameObject>();
        public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
        public bool loop = false;
    
        private int objectstoteleportindex = 0;
        private int teleportersindex = 0;
        private bool startnewcoroutine = false;
    
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move(3));
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            if(teleportersindex != teleporters.Count && startnewcoroutine == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(Move(3));
    
                startnewcoroutine = false;
            }
            
            if(teleportersindex == teleporters.Count && loop == true)
            {
                teleportersindex = 0;
            }
        }
    
        IEnumerator Move(int SecondsToWait)
        {
            objectsToTeleport[objectstoteleportindex].transform.position = teleporters[teleportersindex].transform.position;
    
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(SecondsToWait);
    
            teleportersindex++;
            startnewcoroutine = true;
        }
    }
```

This is working fine. There is one object to teleport that at the start move to the first teleporter and each 3 seconds it moves to the next teleporter.

But now I want to make one more thing :

- If I have for example 10 objectsToTeleport and not 1 how can I make that the first one like now will move to the first teleporter after 3 seconds when it moves to the second teleporter only then send the second objectsToTeleport to the first teleporter and so on so it will make some kind of cycle of the objectsToTeleport moving between the teleporters.
- and in general if I have for example 10 objectsToTeleport how do I make them all move between the teleporters ? doing it with 1 was easy.

And this is the script version with random teleporter select now there are two objects to teleport and each object each time is moving to a random teleporter :

But still I don't understand how to make the objects to teleport to move in the same order between the teleporters(waypoints) but with delay between them. The first object go to teleporter 1 after 3 seconds the first object go to teleporter 2 and the second object go to teleporter 1 and so on each 3 seconds they move to the next teleporter with delay of 3 seconds between them.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToTeleport = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public bool loop = false;

    private int objectstoteleportindex = 0;
    private int teleportersindex = 0;
    private bool startnewcoroutine = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move(3));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(teleportersindex != teleporters.Count && startnewcoroutine == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move(3));

            startnewcoroutine = false;
        }
        
        if(teleportersindex == teleporters.Count && loop == true)
        {
            teleportersindex = 0;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move(int SecondsToWait)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToTeleport.Count; i++)
        {
            var teleporter = Random.Range(0, teleporters.Count);
            objectsToTeleport[i].transform.position = teleporters[teleporter].transform.position;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(SecondsToWait);

        teleportersindex++;
        
        //objectstoteleportindex++;
        
        startnewcoroutine = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I didn't since I'm not sure how to start with multiple objects so I'm stuck at this point where it's working but only with one object to teleport.

Comment: Your question is difficult to read due to the run-on sentences. It really helps if you use punctuation to make your question more legible. Your code looks like it should be about right, but I'm not sure I'm understanding your question.